# Get user list of SO whose bio contains given words

Tags: support, data-explorer

I know that we can get data from the **Stack Overflow** database using a query.

I wanted to get data about whose bios contain some given words.

For example, If I put `flutter, kotlin` then I will get a list of users whose bio contains `flutter, kotlin`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's stored in the `Users.AboutMe` field in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), so it's a [relatively simple query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1114065/search-user-bios?query1=flutter&query2=kotlin) giving 8 results:

[image]

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. If you're interested, take the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) to learn how to write these kind of queries yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Using this [data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1114064/get-user-list-of-so-whose-bio-contains-given-words), you can achieve it:

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Id] AS [User Link]
FROM Users
WHERE AboutMe LIKE '%##SearchText##%'
```

You can pass your required text as the parameter to get the result.

Comment: Nice, didn't know you could use parameters in string literals ...